# How do I make a number go down?

Tags: c++

Here I have made a program that asks how old the user is and how much money they have. Lets say for example the user puts that he/she has $500 and buys a bat for $50. How do I make the $500 go down to $450?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
int money;
cout << "How old are you?" << endl;
cin >> age;
if (age <= 12) {
    cout << "Not for kids. Sorry!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "How much money do you have?" << endl;
}
cin >> money;
if (money <= 50) {
    cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Here are the items you can buy" << endl;
    cout << " a = $50 Bat\n b = $100 Beats\n c = $500 Xbox One\n d = $500 PS4\n";
}
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
if (cin >> a) {
    money -= 50; //This is the part where I tried to make the $500 go down
}
cout << "You have " << money << "left" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

This is the part where I tried to make the $500 go down to $450:

```
if (cin >> a) {
    money -= 50; //This is the part where I tried to make the $500 go down
}
cout << "You have " << money << "left" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Also if there is a way to make my program have the same output as my code but shorter, that would also be great!

Comment: I'm guessing you've entered `a`. That's not how it works. Btw, the preconditions you set do not block anybody from buying anything, if they fail, they just don't print the next question. And `money <= 50` - `50` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You must modify your code to make it logical and readable.
I write this for you.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int age, money;
int priceA = 50, priceB = 100, priceC = 500, priceD = 500;
char choice;

cout << "How old are you?" << endl;
cin >> age;
if (age <= 12) {
    cout << "Not for kids. Sorry!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

cout << "How much money do you have?" << endl;
cin >> money;
if (money <= 50) {
    cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
    return 0;
}

cout << "Here are the items you can buy" << endl;
cout << " a = $ " << priceA << " Bat" << endl;
cout << " b = $ " << priceB << " Bat" << endl;
cout << " c = $ " << priceC << " Bat" << endl;
cout << " d = $ " << priceD << " Bat" << endl;

cin >> choice;

switch (choice) {
  case 'a':
    if(money >= priceA) {
    money -= priceA;
    break;
    } else {
    cout << "You have not enough money!" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
  case 'b':
    if(money >= priceB) {
    money -= priceB;
    break;
    } else {
    cout << "You have not enough money!" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
  case 'c':
    if(money >= priceC) {
    money -= priceC;
    break;
    } else {
    cout << "You have not enough money!" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
  case 'd':
    if(money >= priceD) {
    money -= priceD;
    break;
    } else {
    cout << "You have not enough money!" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
  default:
    cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
    return 0;
 }

cout << "You have " << money << " left" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: it doesn't make sense if i have 51$ and i select Case d than the value will go down to negative numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are representing your user input's choice with a character, read it into a `char`.

Dispatch based on their choice:

```
char choice;
if (cin >> choice) {
  switch (choice) {
  case 'a':
    money -= 50;
    break;
  case 'b':
    money -= 100;
    break;
  case 'c':
    money -= 500;
    break;
  case 'd':
    money -= 500;
    break;
  default:
    std::cerr << "invalid choice";
  }
} else {
  std::cerr << "invalid choice";
}
```

Comment: what if user have 450$ and he/she enters Case d?

Comment: Then `money` would result in `-50`.  Error checking could be added, but I'm keeping the answer simple.

Comment: doesn't make sense brother

Comment: Maybe its a bank card, and your account is now negative.  OP looked like he was struggling to dispatch based on input.  That's what I've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the proper way to solve this question.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int age, money;
int priceA = 50, priceB = 100, priceC = 500, priceD = 500;
char choice;

cout << "How old are you?" << endl;
cin >> age;
if (age <= 12) {
    cout << "Not for kids. Sorry!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

cout << "How much money do you have?" << endl;
cin >> money;
if (money <= 50) {
    cout << "Sorry not enough" << endl;
    return 0;
}

cout << "Here are the items you can buy" << endl;
cout << " a = $ " << priceA << " Bat" << endl;
cout << " b = $ " << priceB << " Bat" << endl;
cout << " c = $ " << priceC << " Bat" << endl;
cout << " d = $ " << priceD << " Bat" << endl;

cin >> choice;

if(choice=='a' && money >=50)
{
   money-=50;
}
if(choice=='b' && money >=100)
{
   money-=100;
}
if(choice=='c' && money >=500)
{
   money-=500;
}
if(choice=='d' && money>=500)
{
   money-=500;
}
cout << "You have " << money << " left" << endl;

return 0;
}
```